# Dealing with unordered_map of abstract classes and serialization

Tags: c++, oop, serialization, boost, abstract

Say I have the following structs:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int get_x() = 0;
}

struct A : Base {
    int get_x() {
         // ...
         return 0;
    }
}

struct B : Base {
    int get_x() {
         // ...
         return 1;
    }
}
```

I also have serialization methods for these classes:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(A);
namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {
        template<class Archive>
        void save(Archive & ar, const A & a,
                        const unsigned int version) {
            // ...
        }
        template<class Archive>
        void load(Archive & ar, A & a,
                        const unsigned int version) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

// same for B
```

In my code, I'm making an `unordered_map<int, A>`. I have functions to save and load this map:

```
inline void save_map(string filename, unordered_map<int, A>& a_dict) {
    ofstream filestream(filename);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(filestream,
                                            boost::archive::no_codecvt);

    archive << a_dict;
}

inline void load_map(string filename, unordered_map<int, A>* a_dict) {
    ifstream filestream(filename);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(filestream,
                                            boost::archive::no_codecvt);

    archive >> *a_dict;
}
```

I now want to generalize my map definition and these functions in an elegant way so my code is agnostic to whether my objects are `A` or `B`. Obviously I run into object slicing issues if I, for example, just start using `unordered_map<int, Base>`, but I've gotten a bit lost in the weeds of pointers at this point and haven't been able to figure out the solution.

Comment: You might consider `unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr <Base>>` or `unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr <Base>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably recommend ready made pointer containers. There are

- [Boost Pointer Containers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)
- Rolling your own

### Pointer Container

This is straight-forward:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/016e970651c52690)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/serialize_ptr_unordered_map.hpp>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() noexcept = default;
    virtual int get_x() const = 0;

    friend auto&  operator<<(std::ostream& os, Base const& b) {
        return os << typeid(b).name() << "[" << b.get_x() << "]";
    }
};

struct A : Base { int get_x() const override { return 0; } };
struct B : Base { int get_x() const override { return 1; } };

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(A)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B)

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Base&, unsigned) { }
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) { ar& base_object<Base>(a); }
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) { ar& base_object<Base>(b); }
}} // namespace boost::serialization

template <typename Map>
inline void save_map(std::string const& filename, Map const& map) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(ofs, boost::archive::no_codecvt);
    archive << map;
}

template <typename Map>
inline void load_map(std::string const& filename, Map& map) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(ifs, boost::archive::no_codecvt);
    archive >> map;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Dict = boost::ptr_unordered_map<int, Base>;

    {
        Dict dict;
        dict.insert(100, std::make_unique<A>());
        dict.insert(200, std::make_unique<B>());
        dict.insert(300, std::make_unique<B>());
        dict.insert(400, std::make_unique<A>());

        save_map("test.bin", dict);
    }

    {
        Dict roundtrip;
        load_map("test.bin", roundtrip);

        for (auto const& [k,v]: roundtrip) {
            std::cout << k << ": " << *v << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
100: 1A[0]
200: 1B[1]
300: 1B[1]
400: 1A[0]
```

And no memory leaks.

---

## Roll your own

This has some benefits (more modern interfaces sometimes somewhat more "pointery" interface at other points):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85b419fe5cbe082d)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/boost_unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() noexcept = default;
    virtual int get_x() const = 0;

    friend auto&  operator<<(std::ostream& os, Base const& b) {
        return os << typeid(b).name() << "[" << b.get_x() << "]";
    }
};

struct A : Base { int get_x() const override { return 0; } };
struct B : Base { int get_x() const override { return 1; } };

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(A)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B)

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Base&, unsigned) { }
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) { ar& base_object<Base>(a); }
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) { ar& base_object<Base>(b); }
}} // namespace boost::serialization

template <typename Map>
inline void save_map(std::string const& filename, Map const& map) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(ofs, boost::archive::no_codecvt);
    archive << map;
}

template <typename Map>
inline void load_map(std::string const& filename, Map& map) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(ifs, boost::archive::no_codecvt);
    archive >> map;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Dict = boost::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Base> >;

    {
        Dict dict;
        dict.emplace(100, std::make_unique<A>());
        dict.emplace(200, std::make_unique<B>());
        dict.emplace(300, std::make_unique<B>());
        dict.emplace(400, std::make_unique<A>());

        save_map("test.bin", dict);
    }

    {
        Dict roundtrip;
        load_map("test.bin", roundtrip);

        for (auto const& [k,v]: roundtrip) {
            std::cout << k << ": " << *v << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints, again without memory leaks, something like:

```
100: 1A[0]
200: 1B[1]
300: 1B[1]
400: 1A[0]
```